# Format a HTML table

Tags: html, formatting

I am a beginner to HTML, and I have a problem formatting my table.

```
<table border="1" width="100%" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="50%" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="33%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="33%" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="34%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to create a table like this:

```
[-----|-----]
[---|---|---]
```

And it creates something like this:

```
[-----|-----]
[-----|---|-]
```

How can I format like that?

Comment: I suggest you to switch to divs as table layouts are deprecated these days :)

Comment: What sort of crazy data do you have where that would be appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `colspan` attribute for this formatting :

Use the LCM [least common multiple] or its multiple of the no of columns in the both rows as the max colspan

In this case i.e LCM[2,3]=6 so you can use 6 or 12 or 18 ...  it's up to you

Now set the `colspan` values accordingly: if you consider max colspan = 6 then

```
<table border="1" width="100%" id="table1">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Or  if you consider max colspan = 12 then

```
<table border="1" width="100%" id="table1">
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing

```
<table border="1" width="100%" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

By using the smallest commmon multiple as the "real" number of columns you can distribute them like you wanted

Still, a better solution is doing as suggested in the comments and use divs